# Delete seleted button generated dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dynamic-controls

I have developed a winform application in C#. I want to generate buttons dynamically on button click, lets name it "Add". On clicking any button randomly, then clicking delete button, that selected button should be deleted. Now how can I do this?

here is my dynamically button generation code

---

```
public void AddNewButton()
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Button();
    Btn = new Button();
    this.Controls.Add(Btn);
    Btn.Name = textBox_code.Text + count;
    Btn.Location = new Point(50, 50);
    Btn.Text = textBox_code.Text;
    Btn.BackColor = Color.Red;
    Btn.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
    Btn.Click += new EventHandler(this.button_Click);
    count = count + 1;
    label1.Text = count.ToString();
    Btn.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(textbox_MouseDown);
    Btn.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(textbox_MouseMove);
    Btn.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(textbox_MouseUp);
}
```

---

and for deleting the button

```
private void button_delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Controls.Remove(Btn);
    count = count - 1;
    label1.Text = count.ToString();
}
```

This above code deletes only last added button not any random selected button

Comment: Explain it a bit more. When you click the delete button, what button should be deleted?

Comment: you should add a handler to Btn.MouseClick and save the last clicked Button in a variable. Then you know which Button was clicked and can remove it in button_delete_Click

Comment: Quite frankly I don't know how your dynamic button generation code compiles

Comment: OP probably made a mistake with the `System.Windows.Forms.Button();` I think we can assume that it should be `System.Windows.Forms.Button Btn;`

Answer (score 2):

Add a variable to hold the last clicked button (at the class level)

```
Button lastClicked = null;
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs args) 
{
    ...
}
```

In your `button_Click` add this,

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs args) 
{
    // whatever you already have...

    lastClicked = (Button)sender;
}
```

And then in your delete button handler,

```
private void button_delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // delete the last clicked button
    this.Controls.Remove(lastClicked);
    count = count - 1;
    label1.Text = count.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't explain how you select the button to be deleted, but as a general answer using the name of the button, instead of

```
this.Controls.Remove(Btn);
```

What about

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
     if (c.Name == "Name of button to delete")
     {
           this.Controls.Remove(c);
           break;
     }
}
```

**EDIT**

Ok, you do explain the process. Then a way to do it is to have a variable to store the last clicked button:

```
Button btnLastClicked;
```

Then in the button_Click event handler, do this:

```
btnLastClicked=sender as Button;
```

Finally,

```
private void button_delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Controls.Remove(btnLastClicked);
    count = count - 1;
    label1.Text = count.ToString();
}
```

Comment: He explains it: *on click any button randomly then clicking delete button that selected button should b deleted*

Comment: Ok ok,you are right, i didn't read it carefully, you can stop those -1 :)

Comment: SO is full of savages.

Comment: Removed the downvote. @mike and Pikoh the answer did not properly address the question, was it wrong to downvote it?

Comment: You're wellcome Nidzz :). If it works, you should accept one answer, mike's or mine.